# Convert String to HTML tag and assign into google map api

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have the following variable:

```
  var htmlInput ="<input id="userloc" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search your location">"
```

I want to convert this whole strings into HTML element and insert it into google map as follow:

```
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(htmlInput);
```

I understood that Google search box only accepts HTML element, so I have to convert htmlInput strings to html tag format, which need to be exactly as shown above. How can I achieve this? i tried $.parseHTML() function but it is not successful.

Comment: why you don't get the element like this: `var htmlInput = document.getElementById('userloc');`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to query for your HTML element. In your case you can get the target DOM element like this.

```
var htmlInput = document.getElementById("userLoc");
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(htmlInput);
```

Please refer to the documentation properly https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

Answer (score 0):

U can use jQuery or javascript to convert html to DOM object;

```
//usingjQuery 
var htmlInput = $('<input id="userloc" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search your location" />');
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(htmlInput);
```